# Get white blank screen in flutter navigation SDK

Tags: flutter, heremaps

You can refer screenshoot [Image attach here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xW9GQ.jpg)

And in android also happening same getting this error

message='{"error":"Forbidden","error_description":"These credentials do not authorize access"}'

Answer (score 0):

The credentials you have set are not valid for the *Navigate Editon*. See this [note](https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/dev_guide/topics/quick-start.html#get-your-credentials) how to get credentials.